# Redirect home URL to main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect home controller to my domain, it should look like this

```
http://sample.com/home to http://sample.com

http://sample.com/home/index to http://sample.com

http://localhost:8888/sample/home to http://localhost:8888/sample/

http://localhost:8888/sample/home/index to http://localhost:8888/sample/
```

is it possible? And how to do it?

Comment: if home is your default controller. This is possible : http://sample.com/home to http://sample.com

Comment: //301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://sample.com/home http://sample.com

Comment: @bugfixer can you elaborate how?

Comment: Seems you have directories in controllers directory. With no sub-directories you could try something like [this](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/) (check first rule written) in `.htaccess` file. For sub-directories included you need to extend regex in apache accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to redirect to home page `redirect('/');`

[URL Helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

On your config base_url() make sure is set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://sample.com/';
```

You may need to remove index.php and have a suitable htaccess file in main directory.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Htaccess example for main directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Your home controller route should the be set on default route application -> config -> routes.php

[Codeigniter URI Routing User Guide Page](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

Then autoload url helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

The if you need to redirect to home controller make sure file name Home.php

and use `redirect('/');`

Note: Codeigniter 3 is case sensitive make sure first letter all ways upper case on file name and class name

Comment: Most of this answer is about routing. I'm expecting redirecting using htaccess

Comment: Are you a fellow New Zealander